# Given a sequence of sets, choose one element from each to get the lowest number of changes

Tags: assignment-problem

Let $k,n \in \mathbb{N} $ and non empty sets $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,k\}$.

Define the change counting cost function $f: X_1 \times X_2 \times \dots \times X_n \to \mathbb{N}$ by $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = \sum_{i=2}^n\delta(i)$

where $\delta(i) = 1$ if $x_i \neq x_{i-1}$ and otherwise $0$

How can we find $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \in X_1 \times X_2 \times \dots \times X_n$ which minimizes the cost function?

For example consider the sets sequence: $\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}$ a solution can be one of $(1, 3, 3, 3)$ $(2,3,3,3), (2,2,3,3)$ which have one change. this is minimal because the sets' intersection is empty and hence we can't find a zero change vector.

Is there any efficient way to solve this?

We have $k^n$ options to check in the worst case, so by brute force, we have exponential time.

I read about the [Assigment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) but couldn't model it to fit it, though I'm not sure this can't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every I = 1 to n, and for every x in xi, calculate the cheapest sequence for the first I sets ending in x.

For I = 1 it is trivial, every sequence has cost 0.

To find the cheapest sequence for I+1 sets ending in x, the cost is either the cheapest sequence for I sets ending in x or the cost of any sequence for I sets ending in anything other than I, plus 1.

Total cost is the sum of (element count of set I-1, timed element count of set I).

Albert Hendrik's method is easier and faster in this case, but this method can be applied to any situation where the cost is a function of your choice in set I and your choice in set I+1. For example if the cost is the absolute difference between two numbers or something more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You can just greedily take the element of the first set that appears in the most consecutive sets (decide equals arbitrarily). That's the first element of your solution. Then do the same for the next set after those consecutive sets.